# Kafka tool и не используемые consumers group

Tags: apache-kafka

У нас в Kafka используется около десятка рабочих **consumer group**. Однако в `Kafka tool 2.0.1` отображаются все consumer(ы) за всю историю ее использования.

Хотелось бы убрать лишние, но не знаю как это сделать, ведь смещения хранятся в спец. топике **__consumer_offests**. Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Может как нибудь вычитать сообщения из  **__consumer_offests**??? Подскажите плиз куда копать?

[image: Список всех consumers]

Answer (score 1):

Если группы хранятся, в Zookeeper'е и вы знаете, какие именно группы "лишние", тогда:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper <zookeeper_url> --delete --group <group_name>
```

Если группы хранятся в самой Кафке (в том самом топике __consumer_offests), то они удаляются автоматически, как только истечек срок последнего закоммиченного оффсета (настройка `offsets.retention.minutes`). До версии 2.0.0 значение по умолчанию было `1440` (1 день), с версии 2.0.0 его [подняли](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_200_notable) до 7 дней.

Comment: Все это верно если вручную получать список живых `consumer_group`, например как то так `./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list ...`. 
Но речь идет именно о просмотре групп через `Kafka tool > 2.0`. С увеличением групп увеличиваются `Partition` в топике `__consumer_offests`. Теоритически можно удалить этот топик хранащий смещения, но это не является решением пригодным для использвания.